# How to determine the smallest common divisor of a string?

Tags: string, algorithm

I was asked the following question during a job interview and was stumped by it.

Part of the problem I had is making up my mind about what problem I was solving. At first I didn't think the question was internally consistent but then I realized it is asking you to solve two different things - the first task is to figure out whether one string contains a multiple of another string. But the second task is to find a smaller unit of division within both strings.

It's a bit more clear to me now with the pressure of the interview room behind me but I'm still not sure what the ideal algorithm would be here. Any suggestions?

```
Given two strings s & t, determine if s is divisible by t.
For example: "abab" is divisible by "ab"
But "ababab" is not divisible by "abab".
If it isn't divisible, return -1.
If it is, return the length of the smallest common divisor:
So, for "abababab" and "abab", return 2 as s is divisible 
by t and the smallest common divisor is "ab" with length 2.
```

Comment: *Common* divisor of *one* value looks a misnomer. (Proper) *Divisibility* of one string by another should be easy (watch out for pitfalls like *empty string*). A *proper divisor* of *one* string also should not be hard to find.

Comment: I don't understand the terminology.  By straight adaptation of the mathematical term, taking the "concatenation" definition of `*` for strings, then "ababab" and "abab" have a smallest common divisor of "ab".  "abababab" and "abab" have a smallest common divisor of "abab".  *No* common divisor would be strings without a repeating pattern in common, such as "divisor" and "common".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oddly, you're asked to return -1 unless s is divisible by t (which is easy to check), and then you're only left with cases where t divides s.

If t divides s, then the smallest common divisor is just the smallest divisor of t.

The simplest way to find the smallest divisor of t is to check all the factors of its length to see if the prefix of that length divides t.

You can do it in linear time by building the Knuth-Morris-Pratt search table for t:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

This will tell you all the suffixes of t that are also prefixes of t.  If the length of the remainder divides the length of t, then the remainder divides t.

Answer (score 0):

let n is the length of the string s and m is the length of string t, then first we find the gcd(greatest common divisor) of n & m(the largest length that divides both n & m), now we find the all the divisors of gcd in O(square root of gcd) then, we start checking each of them in increasing order whether the starting substring of s or t of length l(divisors of gcd) exist n/l && (m/l) times(using kmp algorithm or robin karp hashing method or rolling hash), if yes, then we break and return length l otherwise we keep checking it until we run out of the divisors and return -1 if nothing is found.