# Runtime for finding smallest common divisor of 2 strings

Tags: java, string, time-complexity, big-o, space-complexity

I took a stab at this question here: [How to determine the smallest common divisor of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59549234/how-to-determine-the-smallest-common-divisor-of-a-string)

I think I have the right implementation, but I'm not sure about the time and space complexities. It seems like it's linear for both. However, the first for-loop check is throwing me off for the time complexity. The StringBuilder is also tricky for the space complexity.

Here's what I coded up:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "bcdbcdbcdbcd", t1 = "bcdbcd";
    String s2 = "bcdbcdbcd", t2 = "bcdbcd";
    String s3 = "lrbb", t3 = "lrbb";
    System.out.println(getLength(s1, t1));
    System.out.println(getLength(s2, t2));
    System.out.println(getLength(s3, t3));
}

private static int getLength(String s, String t) {
    if(s.length() % t.length() > 0)
        return -1;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i*t.length() < s.length();i++) {
        sb.append(t);
    }
    if(!sb.toString().equals(s))
        return -1;
        
    int divisible = 1;
    
    for(int i=1;i<=t.length();i++) {
        
       if(t.length()%divisible++ != 0) {
            continue;
        }
         
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        String subStr = t.substring(0, i);
        while(sb.length() < t.length()) {
            sb.append(subStr);
        }
        if(sb.toString().equals(t))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Current implementation's complexity:

Let n=|s|, m=|t|

Time:

```
O(n/m+m^2)
```

Space:

```
O(n+m)
```